# Android Download File Error Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded video files into the S3 Amazon bucket, and I'm trying to download the S3object and parse the data into a file using the code below:

```
    InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(object.getObjectContent());
    File file = new File("media");
    OutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

    int read = -1;

    while ((read = reader.read()) != -1) {
        writer.write(read);
    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);

        is.close();
```

However, I am faced with a **java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) error**, and I am not sure why. Can anyone explain why?

I referenced the code from: [AWS S3 Java SDK - Download file help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903255/aws-s3-java-sdk-download-file-help)

Comment: Check if the file is public, if not right click on the file and choose make public on the amazon AWS console.

Comment: I made it public on the console, but the error still comes up :/

Comment: In the AWS web console it self, there might be nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I believe this (`File file = new File("media");`) is incorrect. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html